# How to convert raw response into image(Image is not showing)

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

Angular Code:

```
$scope.displayTaskOutput = function() {
        alert("hey display...")
        console.log("Selected jobId is...."+$scope.widgetForm.query_config.selectedTasks.jobId)
        console.log("Selected File is....."+$scope.widgetForm.query_config.selectedFiles)

        $http({
                url: baseUrl+"/"+$scope.widgetForm.query_config.selectedTasks.jobId+"/download",
                method: "GET",
                params: {fileName:$scope.widgetForm.query_config.selectedFiles},
                headers: {
                    'x-api-key': apiKey,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/binary'
                },
                 data: ''


            }).then(function(response, status) {

                console.log("Success data.....")
                console.log(response);
    $scope.taskOutputData = response.data;


            })
    };
```

Html code:

Here the image is not getting rendered but something is coming in encrypted format.
The output from the http call is coming in raw format.How can I convert into image

Comment: Could you please show your html code?

Comment: I think you need angularjs-crypto. Please check this link 
http://angular-js.in/angular-crypto/